# Dotcloud: how to load a redis backup file on startup

Tags: redis, dotcloud

I can't find a way to have redis load my own dump.rdb backup file on startup, on dotcloud. I can see in the server logs that redis is loading a file, but I don't know where it is (and I can't find it)

```
[144] 03 Jul 21:01:18 * DB loaded from disk: 0 seconds
```

I've tried to put the dump.rdb file in `/var/lib/redis` directory but it doesn't help

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found what I made wrong: upon restart, redis makes a dump, and was overwriting my dump file with an empty dump and reloading the empty dump on startup. Correct process is:

```
~$ dotcloud ssh [your service]
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/redis stop
~$ cp [your dump] /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/redis start
```